# Fit-PC as a Lightweight Linux Server?

Tags: linux

What are some good systems for running a lightweight Linux server.  Typical uses:

- Apache Web Server (light access)
- SCP/SSH Server (remote file access / tunnel)
- SVN Server

Important factors:

- Cheap ($300 or less)
- Small
- Energy Efficient

I have been looking at the [Fit-PC](http://fit-pc2.com) as a possible platform for this type of server.  Is this the best way to go?  Is there another option I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered building your own?

The Micro-ATX and Mini-ITX platforms are both quite small and components are very cheap.

For example:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811121090
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813500010

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an even more lightweight Linux server, you could try the [SheevaPlug](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-22-sheevaplug-dev-kit.aspx) devkit. It has a 1.2GHz CPU, 512mb of ram, and GbEthernet and USB2.0 plugs, and you can't get much smaller.

Sadly, it's currently on a four week backorder.

Answer (score 1):

I second the build your own route.

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856167037](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136099)

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134317

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136099

Total cost ~$200. Not bad for a dual core server.  Plus it has hyper threading.

Answer (score 0):

Acer has a new device:
http://aceraspirerevo.com/